# How do I set register_meta for a specific CPT?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I want to set meta for specific CPT. The below code works but it sets the meta for all CPT. How do I set meta for specific CPT? I have a CPT "testimonial" and want to set "_duib_cl_heading" meta for it.

```
function _duib_cl_heading_register_post_meta() {
register_meta(
    'post',
    '_duib_cl_heading',
    [
        'auth_callback' => '__return_true',
        'default'       => __( '', '_duib_cl_heading' ),
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'single'        => true,
        'type'          => 'string',
    ]
);
}
add_action( 'init', '_duib_cl_heading_register_post_meta' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`register_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) has a post type parameter, or just set `object_subtype` to the post type.

```
register_meta(
    'post',
    '_duib_cl_heading',
    [
        'auth_callback'  => '__return_true',
        'default'        => __( '', '_duib_cl_heading' ),
        'show_in_rest'   => true,
        'single'         => true,
        'type'           => 'string',
        'object_subtype' => 'testimonial',
    ]
);
```

Or

```
register_post_meta(
    'testimonial',
    '_duib_cl_heading',
    [
        'auth_callback' => '__return_true',
        'default'       => __( '', '_duib_cl_heading' ),
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'single'        => true,
        'type'          => 'string',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob Peattie. I tried the first option and it didnt work. " 'object_subtype' => 'testimonial', " worked. I wonder why the first option didnt work.